# Using Djisktra Shortest Path on anonyous graph NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I've been using the Dijkstra Source-Target algorithm of the GDSL plugin to get the shortest path between two nodes. That works exactly as it should be, however I always have to rerun the cypher query :

```
CALL gds.graph.create( 'graphname, 'node', 'rel', { relationshipProperties: 'prop' } )
```

or else the Djikstra call gives an " Graph not exist in database".

Anyone has any idea why this keeps happening? or if I can run the djikstra algortihm anonymously ? I searched on the official website however I didn't find a detailed example.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart your Neo4j instance, the named graph gets dropped from the memory. This is the only way you can drop your named graph without explicitly dropping it. If you want to do multiple dijkstra algorithms in sequence it if more performant if you create a named graph, but you can also run dijsktra on an anonymous graph:

```
CALL gds.graph.create( 'graphname, 'node', 'rel', { relationshipProperties: 'prop' } )

MATCH (source:Location {name: 'A'}), (target:Location {name: 'F'})
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream({
    nodeProjection: 'node',
    relationshipProjection:'rel',
    relationshipProperties: ['cost']
    sourceNode: source,
    targetNode: target,
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
YIELD index, sourceNode, targetNode, totalCost, nodeIds, costs, path
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Dijkstra algo in anonymous graph projection, as stated here
[Dijkstra Source-Target Anonymous syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/dijkstra-source-target/#algorithms-dijkstra-single-source-syntax-anonymous)

For the 'graph does not exist' problem, have you tried to use CALL gds.graph.list() to verify it was created? Are you sure somewhere inside your query you are not dropping it?